# Integer.parseInt(scan.next()) or scan.nextInt()?

Tags: java, performance, parseint

I oscillate with using

```
import java.util.Scanner;
.
.
.
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
.
.
. 
Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
```

or

```
import java.util.Scanner;
.
.
.    
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
.
.
.
scan.nextInt();
```

Which one is more useful, or more precisely; which would be running faster?

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak A `java.util.Scanner`.

Comment: @Josh. I bow to your mind reading abilities ( and the knowledge of Java libraries ) :)

Comment: Sorry, I've just made the corrections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now granted, this is just the Sun implementation, but below is the nextInt(int radix) implementation.

Note that it uses a special pattern (`integerPattern()`). This means if you use `next()` you'll be using your default pattern. Now if you just made a `new Scanner()` you'll be using a typical whitespace pattern. But if you used a different pattern, you can't be certain you'll be picking up a word. You might be picking up a line or something.

In the general case I would highly recommend `nextInt()`, since it provides you with an abstraction, giving you less that's likely to go wrong, and more information when something does.

Read this at your leisure:

```
public int nextInt(int radix) {
    // Check cached result
    if ((typeCache != null) && (typeCache instanceof Integer)
    && this.radix == radix) {
        int val = ((Integer)typeCache).intValue();
        useTypeCache();
        return val;
    }
    setRadix(radix);
    clearCaches();
    // Search for next int
    try {
        String s = next(integerPattern());
        if (matcher.group(SIMPLE_GROUP_INDEX) == null)
            s = processIntegerToken(s);
        return Integer.parseInt(s, radix);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        position = matcher.start(); // don't skip bad token
        throw new InputMismatchException(nfe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling is that scan.nextInt, a scan.next could read in newlines or whitespace or other garbage. Might take longer to sift through the junk chars

Answer (score 0):

For which one is faster , I think manually parsing Integer.parseInt is faster, as  scan.nextInt would do a regex based match and then do an Integer.parseInt on that value

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

nextInt() method is more handy.

Use Integer.parseInt() when you are applying user validation.

Suppose you want your program to take user input as 5 , and you want to display custom message when user types '---5' , where '--' are whitespaces.
In that case Integer.parseInt() is helpful.